# What would cause a javascript modal pop-up to work in IE7 but not IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, modal-dialog

I'm working with two modal pop-ups. One is a transparent grey screen to overlay the screen and the other is a box that should sit ontop of the gray modal. Well, the grey modal stop halfway down the page, and the other displays at the bottom of the page.

The page works as intended in IE7 but it displays as posted above in IE8 and 9.

I'm wondering if there are any general problems that would cause the issue (Key differences between 7 and 8).

One general issue that I've tried already is the doctype. Mine is

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

// loads control as modal window. if element passed in then uses it for placement otherwise it

```
//creates a new element in the body.
toModal: function (element) {

    this.modalid = createModal(770, 500);
    this.show(this.modalid);
},


var controlID = '_modal_' + modalWindows.length;
var currYpos = document.viewport.getScrollOffsets()[1];

var windowWidth = document.viewport.getWidth();
var windowHeight = document.viewport.getHeight();

var tp = (windowHeight - height) / 2;
var lt = (windowWidth - width) / 2;

tp = tp + currYpos;  //+ 75;
currYpos = currYpos;  //+ 145;

var modal = new Element('div', { 'id': controlID, 'class': 'modalBox', 'style': 'top:' + tp + '; left:' + lt + '; z-index:10000' + modalWindows.length + '; width:' + width + '; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; height:' + height + ';overflow:auto;' });
var modalBack;
if ($('modal_back')) {
    modalBack = $('modal_back');
} else {
    modalBack = new Element('div', { 'id': 'modal_back', 'class': 'modalBack', 'style': 'top:' + 0 + '; left:' + 0 + '; width:' + windowWidth + '; height:' +  docHeight + ';'});
}
modalBack.setOpacity(0.5);

// For IE6 bug regarding SELECT's taking z-index presedence over all non-windowed controls (this is fixed in IE7+)
var version = 999;
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) {
    version = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1]);
}

$(document.body).insert(modalBack);
$(document.body).insert(modal);
```

Comment: Sorry if this is painfully obvious; but are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: Any chance we could get a peek at the HTML/CSS/JS involved? Beyond the doctype, another thing you can check is the HTTP headers/meta tags. If you want them to render identically, you can use something like `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />`. Now that's not _why_ they render differently, but as is it might be that the browsers see the transitional doctype and no X-UA-Compatible info, then go about their own rendering ways.

Comment: I'm not getting any javascript errors and I have the meta tag posted above.

Comment: There are some considerable differences in the CSS implementations of IE7 and IE8/9. Post your HTML/CSS, and we can probably help. Might be how you've set the height of various elements, might be how you've set positioning... or some combination thereof.

Comment: I added the javascript above.